# Add Subview To Current Visible UIViewController in UITabBar when selecting TabBarItem before Loading

Tags: ios

I would like to add a subview with a loading message to the current visible view controller in a tabbarcontroller when the user selects another tabbaritem.

In my subclass of UITabBarController, when I use

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item
```

or

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
```

I can add the view, but the `- (void)viewDidLoad`-Method of the newly selected viewcontroller is somehow blocking the added view.

How can I add a subview to the current visible viewcontroller (or tabbarcontroller's view) ***before*** the newly selected viewcontroller starts loading?

Comment: Are you doing some heavy work in `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: Well, there are quite a lot of things to be done (masking a few UIViews) - in one specific tab. There is a small lag of time before the new view is shown up. Not more than a second, but it's just not nice.

Comment: If you're doing heavy work, then the problem is that the UI thread is being blocked until it's finished, so changing or adding views will have no effect until after the thread is free again... One (very hacky) way that might work is to put `[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0]];` right after adding your view...